# Google In-App Billing product description

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

I am testing In-App Billing for an Android app that uses Google In-App Billing v3. I have one problem that haven't been able to fix so far. When Google Play dialog opens after I start the purchase flow from my app, I cannot see the product description I entered in the Development console. I am able to retrieve this String using getSkuDetails() method, and I can see the description in the Play Store app, but not in the purchase dialog. Could this have something to do with the fact that I am using test purchases?

Comment: I am experiencing the same and wondering as well where the description actually shows up. As well other apps that have in-app billing do not show anything in that dialog.